# Command node -v shows bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi

I have a non working node on my raspberry pi 4 (buster). :(

`npm -v` shows version 6.14.5 and `nodejs -v` shows v10.21.0 but `node -v` shows only
"bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory"

But a file named /usr/local/bin/node is there.

The Command

```
n latest
```

shows

```
installing : node-v14.6.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/14.6.0
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.6.0/node-v14.6.0-linux-arm64.tar.xz
/usr/local/bin/n: line 633: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
   installed :  (with npm 6.14.6)
```

Comment: Can you please verify if the file at `/usr/local/bin/node` has execute permissions?

Comment: @GabrielMilan. `$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/node`

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 40753472 Jul 22 18:33 /usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it

Remove the files in *usr/local/bin/node* using this command ***sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node****. You could optionally choose to manually remove npx, n or whichever node related package that you've installed

Run ***sudo apt install nodejs*** and then check the version using ***node -v***

Run ***sudo apt install npm*** then ***npm -v***

After that, run  ***curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash*** then *restart the terminal*

Finally run ***nvm install 16***

This should solve your issue, it did for me!